# rails Nested Form Table, Calling Each in View (Only) Returns the Last Record Multiple Times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, nested-forms

I have a nested association: state_registrations belong to sponsors.  When I try to show the sponsor state_registrations in the view using each, I only get the last record and it prints three times (the total number of state_registrations in my table)

`sponsors / _form` aka `edit` creates the table:

```
<%= f.nested_fields_for :state_registrations, 
    wrapper_tag: :div do |state_registration_fields| %>
<div class="row" >
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <%= state_registration_fields.label :state_license, "State" %>
    <%= state_registration_fields.select :state_license, 
      options_for_select(@state_licenses), {}, {class: "state_license
      form-control btn-default btn-block", id: "state_license"} %>
  </div> ....
```

Table - i.e., what's being saved, here, three state_registrations were successively created for a single sponsor with id: '2' (They're out of order because I edited them using the console):

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [
#<StateRegistration id: 8, state_license_number: "CA-1", state_license_name: "CTEC", 
  sponsor_id: 2, created_at: "2016-01-23 23:45:22", updated_at: "2016-01-24 00:41:50", state_license: "California", course_id: nil>,
#<StateRegistration id: 7, state_license_number: "OR-2", state_license_name: "TP", 
  sponsor_id: 2, created_at: "2016-01-23 22:12:07", updated_at: "2016-01-24 00:42:06", state_license: "Oregon", course_id: nil>,
#<StateRegistration id: 9, state_license_number: "MD-1", state_license_name: "ITP", 
  sponsor_id: 2, created_at: "2016-01-24 00:31:44", updated_at: "2016-01-24 00:42:19", state_license: "Maryland", course_id: nil>]>
```

Better stated, `state_license` California, `state_license_name` CTEC, `state_license_number` CA-1, which correspond to the expected view output.

I have three state_registrations: California (id: 8), Oregon (id: 7), and Maryland (id: 9)

Sponsors controller `show`

```
def show
  @sponsor = Sponsor.find(params[:id])
  @sponsor = current_sponsor
  @sponsor.state_registrations = StateRegistration
    .where('sponsor_id = ?', current_sponsor.id)
    .limit(10).order('state_license asc')
  ....
```

`sponsor.rb`

```
has_many :state_registrations, dependent: :destroy
has_one :state_registration, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :state_registrations,
  :allow_destroy => true,
  :reject_if => lambda { |e| (e[:state_license].blank?) }
def state_registration
  super || build_state_registration
end
```

`state_registration.rb`

```
belongs_to :sponsors
```

`show,htl.erb`, part of a table:

```
<tbody> 
  <% @sponsor.state_registrations.each do |state_license|  %>
  <%#= raise state_registration.inspect %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= @sponsor.state_registration.state_license %></td>
      <%#= raise @sponsor.state_registration.state_license.inspect %>
      <td><%= @sponsor.state_registration.state_license_name %></td>
      <td><%= @sponsor.state_registration.state_license_number %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

I intentionally left the commented out `raise`:

```
<%= raise state_registration.inspect %>  # returns California, as 
  expected - because I sorted in asc order on `state_license` in
  the controller and its first alphabetically

<%= raise @sponsor.state_registration.state_license.inspect %> #returns
  Maryland, the last record in the table (id: 9)
```

Now, the curious thing I see in the rails server output is `LIMIT 1` which suggests it only returning one record, the last one.  I don't understand why `raise state_registration` returns California and `raise @sponsor.state_registration.state_license` returns Maryland - in the same `show.html.erb` refresh

What is seen in the browser [ at `http://localhost:3000/sponsors/2` ] is three identical lines in the table:

```
State      License Name     License Number        
Maryland   ITP              MD-1
Maryland   ITP              MD-1
Maryland   ITP              MD-1
```

Here's the rails server output:

```
Started GET "/sponsors/2" for ::1 at 2016-01-23 20:51:14 -0600
Processing by SponsorsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
Sponsor Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "sponsors".* FROM "sponsors" 
  WHERE "sponsors"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "sponsors"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
    [["id", 2]]
Sponsor Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "sponsors".* FROM "sponsors" 
  WHERE "sponsors"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
```

I'm 'splitting' the log to show that here StateRegistration loads LIMIT 10 per the sponsor controller

```
StateRegistration Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "state_registrations".* 
  FROM "state_registrations" WHERE (sponsor_id = 2)  
  ORDER BY state_license asc LIMIT 10
StateRegistration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "state_registrations".* 
  FROM "state_registrations" 
  WHERE "state_registrations"."sponsor_id" = $1  [["sponsor_id", 2]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  COMMIT
(0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "cpe_events" 
  WHERE (sponsor_display_name = 'IL - TEST') 
  AND (class_date >= '2016-01-23')
(0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "cpe_events" 
   WHERE (sponsor_display_name = 'IL - TEST') 
   AND (class_date <= '2016-01-23')
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "sponsors".* FROM "sponsors" 
  WHERE "sponsors"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
Photo Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "photos".* FROM "photos" 
  WHERE "photos"."sponsor_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["sponsor_id", "2"]]
Instructor Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "instructors".* FROM "instructors" 
  WHERE "instructors"."sponsor_id" = $1  [["sponsor_id", 2]]
Instructor Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "instructors".* FROM "instructors" 
  WHERE "instructors"."sponsor_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["sponsor_id", 2]]
Photo Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "photos".* 
  FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."instructor_id" = $1 LIMIT 1
    [["instructor_id", "16"]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "state_registrations".* 
 FROM "state_registrations" WHERE (sponsor_id = 2)  
 ORDER BY state_license asc LIMIT 10
```

However, here it shows LIMIT 1 - I don't know if this is the cause of my problem or not.

```
StateRegistration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "state_registrations".* 
  FROM "state_registrations" 
  WHERE "state_registrations"."sponsor_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  
    [["sponsor_id", 2]]
(1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" 
  ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" 
  WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = $1  [["followed_id", 2]]
Rendered shared/_sponsor_stats.html.erb (6.0ms)
CpeEvent Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "cpe_events" 
  WHERE "cpe_events"."sponsor_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["sponsor_id", 2]]
Rendered sponsors/show.html.erb within layouts/application (111.1ms)
Rendered shared/_google_analytics.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered shared/_html5_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_navigation_top.html.erb (4.6ms)
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.3ms)
Rendered shared/_navigation_bottom.html.erb (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1899ms (Views: 1867.4ms | ActiveRecord: 12.1ms)
```

Vexing!  I've tried a variety of approaches to resolving this.  E.g., limit / no limit to the number of records, defining `@sponsor.state_registrations` in the controller and view, and defining `@state_registrations` as `StateRegistration.where('sponsor_id =?', current_sponsor.id)` so I could iterate over `@state_registrations` rather than `@sponsor.state_registrations` using `each`; however, I still get the last record (Maryland) three times.

I sincerely hope its something simple and my inexperience that's preventing me from resolving this.  I think I need a good resource for nested forms.

Any help would be appreciated, including pointing me to the appropriate docs.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at your `show` code:

```
<tbody> 
  <% @sponsor.state_registrations.each do |state_license|  %>
  <%#= raise state_registration.inspect %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= @sponsor.state_registration.state_license %></td>
      <%#= raise @sponsor.state_registration.state_license.inspect %>
      <td><%= @sponsor.state_registration.state_license_name %></td>
      <td><%= @sponsor.state_registration.state_license_number %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The problem here is you're calling `state_registration` method, which is a has_one association (but the iteration variable is named `state_license`). Essentially, you're just calling the same has_one association in a loop.  Why do you have has_many and has_one association that points to the same foreign key in the first place?

```
has_many :state_registrations, dependent: :destroy
has_one :state_registration, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I (1) removed the `has_one :state_registration` from `sponsor.rb`,  and (2) changed the `belongs_to :sponsors` in `state_registration.rb` to `has_many`.  Now, in the view, the line `@sponsor.state_registration.state_license` throws the error `undefined method state_registration for #<Sponsor...`  I have `state_registration` defined as `@state_registration = StateRegistration.find(params[:id])` in both the sponsors and state_registrations' controllers.  What's still wrong with how I'm accessing the state_registrations table.  Thanks!

Comment: If, following the RoR Guides [ section 4.3.1.13 ], I define `state_registration` as `@state_registration = @sponsor.state_registrations.build(state_registration_params)`, I get the error `undefined method `state_license' for nil:NilClass` so I'm still missing something.